# Redirect domain1.com to domain2.com and keeping domain1.com url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I own 2 domains, and I want that domain2.com "launch" a page on domain1.com/folder/, without redirecting the user to domain1.com/folder/

And I want to do that for few pages, like this :
domain2.com/xxx => domain1.com/folder/yyy

On domain2.com I created this .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectPermanent http://www.domain2.com/ http://www.domain1.com/folder/
RedirectPermanent http://www.domain2.com/xxx http://www.domain1.com/folder/yyy
```

What kind of .htaccess do I have to put on domain1.com to "allow" the fact that the URL doesn't change ?

Comment: You don’t want external redirects then, so all of the `Redirect` directives don’t help you here. You’ll want to use a `RewriteRule`, and depending on what your specific setup for those domains is (are they both pointing to the same folder, is one an alias of the other, …) you might be able to get this done with an internal redirect - or you might need to use mod_proxy and the `[P]` flag.

Comment: Do you mean something like that ?
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "https://www.domain1.com/$1" [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://www.domain1.com/"